# File local export filter functions - Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have the following code within an org file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports both :results none :eval export
(defun my-html-body-onload-filter (output backend info)
  "Add my onload attribute to<body>  tag, if any."
  (when (and (eq backend 'html)
             (string-match "<body>\n" output))
    (replace-match "<body onLoad=\"setUp();\">\n" nil nil output)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
           'my-html-body-onload-filter)
#+END_SRC
```

The problem with this setup is that it permanently adds this function to the list, so that every org-mode file that I export goes through the same filters.

How can I make these filters file local?
I tried using the following too, but it didn't work, i.e., the export was not filtered:

```
# Local variables:
# eval: (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions 'my-html-body-onload-filter)
# End:
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `(make-variable-buffer-local 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions)` to your source block.  This will make changes to the variable local to the current buffer.